# The $×$ in a QFT text is cross product? I 'dont think so

Tags: vectors, quantum-electrodynamics, notation

My friend said that the $×$ that appears in quantum field theory is a vector product but it makes no sense several times I solved the rules of Feynman and never had a vector product for me it is obvious but to him not to, explain there, The image has the $×$ it down to those who did not understand what I said.

[image]

Comment: This is jarringly large. It's generally advisable to type out the actual text using MathJax.There is a helpful introduction [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This is from Schwartz 14.3.2, Page 263, Path Integrals, if anyone wants to know

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Comment: It's just standard multiplication man. This is used throughout the book when equations span multiple lines.

Comment: ... and not only in THAT book.. almost everywhere!

Answer (score 5):

This is a standard way to write multiplication between two scalars for multi-line equations.

Comment: Or in this case, what looks like the action of an operator.

Comment: Indeed. Hard to tell from the image though.